# How to Change the text color in settings app for iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios5.1

I am trying to change the text color in some of the apps, such as dialer/contacts, settings, etc. Is there a plist file for that or what.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Can you please elaborate? You want to change the colors that appear in the Settings app? Or you want a setting where the user chooses a color? Or are you talking about the system address book picker view within your own app?

Comment: Oh sorry. I mean like a way to change the text color in the UI settings